# Regex using python printing Unique lines

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a Python script to read in a file and find a pattern and now I want to print the result with no duplicates. Thank you for the help.

This is what I have but it prints duplicate lines.

```
import re

session = open("edd.txt", "r")
regex = re.compile(r'policy \d+')

for line in session:
    four_letter_words = regex.findall(line)
    for word in four_letter_words:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Does the order of the words matter?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates, your algorithm must remember all outputs it has seen so far. One way to do it would be:

```
[...]

all_four_letter_words = set()

for line in session:
    four_letter_words = regex.findall(line)
    for word in four_letter_words:
        if word not in all_four_letter_words:
            print(word)
            all_four_letter_words.add(word)
```

Comment: A list lookup for this seems very inefficient.  A dictionary would be `O(1)` lookup

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a `set`, this will remove duplicates for you.

```
all_four_letter_words = set()

for line in session:
    four_letter_words = regex.findall(line)
    for word in four_letter_words:
        all_four_letter_words.add(word)
```

And then you can use the `set` as you wish. Though bear in mind that a `set` is unsorted, so when you iterate through them they won't keep their ordering.